# What's wrong with the "or" in my "if" statement?

Tags: python

I've tried Google, but I can't find the answer to this simple question.
I hate myself for not being able to figure this out, but here we go.

How do I write an if statement with `or` in it?

For example:

```
if raw_input=="dog" or "cat" or "small bird":
    print "You can have this animal in your house"
else:
    print "I'm afraid you can't have this animal in your house."
```

Comment: your example code is "or"ing the strings, which is not a legal operation.

Comment: @marr It's actually doing `(raw_input == 'dog') or 'cat' or 'small bird'`, so it will return `True` if `raw_input == 'dog'`, or `cat` otherwise

Comment: Oops, you're right, that will always execute. It is or'ing the strings, but this will evaluate to "cat" everytime and since cat is a string and is not empty, it will count as true.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to use `or`, you need to repeat the whole expression each time:

```
if raw_input == "dog" or raw_input == "cat" or raw_input == "small bird":
```

But a better way to do this particular comparison is with `in`:

```
if raw_input in ("dog", "cat", "small bird"):
```

Answer (score 17):

You can put the allowed animals into a [`tuple`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) then use `in` to search for a match

```
if raw_input() in ("dog", "cat", "small bird"):
    print "You can have this animal in your house"
else:
    print "I'm afraid you can't have this animal in your house."
```

You can also use a [`set`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) here, but I doubt it would improve performance for such a small number of allowed animals

```
desired_animal = raw_input()
allowed_animals = set(("dog", "cat", "small bird"))
if desired_animal in allowed_animals:
    print "You can have this animal in your house"
else:
    print "I'm afraid you can't have this animal in your house."
```

Comment: +1 Most pythonic solution presented, could be made more functional, though.

Comment: @marr It was a pretty trivial question, I don't think we need to start refactoring it to make it more "functional"

Comment: @marr75, please feel free to post a more functional answer :)

Comment: @Michael I didn't mean it needed to be, it just seems like "pythonic" is starting to have more functional programming connotations these days, could be just my opinion. @gnibbler the only functional code I can think of (map and then reduce) would be harder to read, probably.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (raw_input=="dog") or (raw_input == "cat") or (raw_input == "small bird"):
  print You can have this animal in your house
else:
  print I'm afraid you can't have this animal in your house.
```

or

```
if raw_input in ("dog", "cat", "small bird"):
  print You can have this animal in your house
else:
  print I'm afraid you can't have this animal in your house.
```

Comment: Not very "pythonic", i've written code like this but I wouldn't recommend it to a new programmer.

Comment: assuming the raw_input is supposed to be the function call raw_input() you would not want to call it 3 times

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
 if raw_input=="dog" or raw_input=="cat" or raw_input=="small bird":
```

Answer (score 0):

```
goodanimals= ("dog" ,"cat","small bird")
print("You can have this animal in your house" if raw_input().strip().lower() in goodanimals
      else "I'm afraid you can't have this animal in your house.")
```